# double assertion on class definition

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface

```
export interface DefElement<G> {
  id: string;
  element: G;
}

export interface DefEvent<T> {
  type: T;
  value: any;
}
```

I want to be able to set the type of the property `type` and `element`.

so like `DefElement<elementType>` then G will be of `ElementType`

so until now everything works.

I would like to make a class, and that class use those 2 interface and binded type. so I want to be able to do the following call

```
ServiceHandler<DefElement<ElementType>,DefEvent<EventType>>()
```

So I made the following

```
export class ServiceHandler<T,G> {
}
```

there is 2 problem doing this.

1) I can't guarantee that G,T are respecting the interface DefElement and DefEvent

2) if I do let `myVar:T;` then `myVar.value`, it will say that there is no type on type T

So I tried to do the following

```
export class ServiceHandler<DefElement<G>,DefEvent<T>> {
}
```

but it say I can't do a "double generic"

I would like to use the latter, because some property will always be defined, but without specifying a parent interface, I will have a compiler error "value does not exist"

my question is how can I implement this double g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you want to do. You can have two type parameters to `ServiceHandler` that you can use as parameters to the other types:

```
export interface DefElement<G> {
    id: string;
    element: G;
}

export interface DefEvent<T> {
    type: T;
    value: any;
}

export class ServiceHandler<G, T> {

    mapOfelement: Map<string, Map<string, DefElement<G>>> = new Map<string, Map<string, DefElement<G>>>();
    groupDispatchers: Map<string, DefEvent<T>> = new Map<string, DefEvent<T>>();
}
```

Or you can have type parameters that must implement the `DefElement` and `DefEvent` interafces:

```
export interface DefElement<G> {
    id: string;
    element: G;
}

export interface DefEvent<T> {
    type: T;
    value: any;
}

export class ServiceHandler<G extends DefElement<any>, T extends DefEvent<any>> {

    mapOfelement: Map<string, Map<string, G>> = new Map<string, Map<string, G>>();
    groupDispatchers: Map<string, T> = new Map<string, T>();
}

let s = new ServiceHandler<{ id: string, element: number}, { type: 'A', value: any}>()
```

Comment: @Bobby from my reading of your clarifications you are looking for the second option in my answer. You want two type parameters that are constrained to implement the interfaces `G extends DefElement<any>` will mean `G` must implement `DefElement`